# Can I visit to a Christian friend who has dogs as pet at their home? How to deal with their invitation?

Tags: dogs

Can I visit to a Christian friend who has dogs as pet at their home? How to deal with their invitation?

I have two kids aged 4 and 7 and not sure what will these dogs do to my kids too

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm in touching something najis. You just have to wash yourself before you want to do your prayers. You can feed and touch it. Owning a dog or praying while najis are things that aren't accepted...

I would avoid letting him know in your first encounters.

If your children are baliq (mature) then let them know that that they should wash themselves before doing their prayers. For your little ones tell them nothing.

once you get home then wash your clothes.

For when to tell your friend? Just follow common sense. Also let them know of your halal diet before. Usually non-Muslims when they invite a Muslim to their house they ask about what they should/shouldn't do, so be prepared to let him know if you are really really uncomfortable, but I personally advise against it. Let your friendship go on.

On the worst case scenario you could tell them that your my wife/children don't do well with dogs.

I'm suggesting all this because in Islam as long as things are not haram, then we are not instructed to do things that would make others (Muslims or not) upset in the name of Islam. That would do harm to the image of Islam.

Answer (score 0):

When we go to market, we face all kinds of animals, dog, pig etc. and we all know how to deal with it.

If the dog is dry, nothing harm if it touch to cloth.

If you feel dog will harm to your kids, say it clearly to your friend, he is your friend man.